# navigating the dom

Tags: jquery

what's the best way to show each blocks' respective sum in the labels provided ?

```
  <div class='block1'><label for='blockSum'>Sum goes here</label>
    <div class='head'>
      <div class='title'>
        <div class='sumMe'>$1.01</div>
      </div>
    </div>          
    <div class='head'>
      <div class='title'>
        <div class='sumMe'>$2.01</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='block2'><label for='blockSum'>Sum goes here</label>
    <div class='head'>
      <div class='title'>
        <div class='sumMe'>$1.01</div>
      </div>
    </div>          
    <div class='head'>
      <div class='title'>
        <div class='sumMe'>$2.01</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: What do you mean "label each block"? Where you want to show the sum? Please be more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming each block as a class `block`:

```
$('.block').each(function() {
    var total = 0; // total in cents
    $(this).find('.sumMe').each(function() {
        var parts = $(this).text().replace('$', '').split('.'); // prepare text
        total += +parts[0] * 100 + (+parts[1] || 0); // compute value in cents
    });
    $(this).find('label').text('$' + (total/100).toFixed(2)); // write sum
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/LkQaS/1/)

Don't use `float` values for computations with money (though there might be easier ways than mine).

Comment: +1 - sensible approach. Small thing: you could use `parts[1] || 0` to get rid of the `if`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.block1,.block2').each(function(){
     var sumValue=0;
     $('.sumMe',this).each(function(i,v){
         sumValue=sumValue+parseFloat($(v).text().replace('$','')||0);
     });
     $('label:first',this).html('$'+sumvalue);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('.block1,.block2').each(function(){
     var total=0;
     $('.sumMe',this).each(function(){
         total = total + parseFloat($(this).text().replace('$',''));
     });

     $(this).find("label").html("$"+total);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick, although using `parseFloat` will result in silly values for money:

```
$('div[class^="block"]').each(function() {
    var total = 0;
    $(this).find(".sumMe").each(function() {
       total += parseFloat($(this).text().replace("$", ""));
    });
    $(this).find("label").text("TOTAL: " + total);
});
```

This finds all `div` elements with class beginning with "block" (note that the `block` class would have to be the first class listed if you have multiple classes), loops through the matched set, converts the required strings to floats, adds up each one as it goes, and writes the result to the `label` element.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
$('div[class^="block"]').each(function() {
    var sum = 0; //create a sum variable for each block
    var block = $(this);
    block
        .find('.sumMe') // find the .sumMe elements for each block
        .each(function() {
           sum += +$(this).text().replace('$', ''); // convert text to number and add to sum 
        })
        .end() // return to block element
        .prepend('Sum of ' + block.attr('class') + ' is ' + Math.round(sum*100)/100); // prepend the sum to the block

});
```

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/r2yq9/